# cual es la forma correcta de conectar los servicios de IoT Hub con Cosmos DB a través de un función event hub?

Tags: azure

```
**Este es mi código:**



   #r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
    #r "nuget: Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"
    #r "nuget: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos"
    #r "nuget: Newtonsoft.Json"
    
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    public static async Task Run(string myIoTHubMessage, out object outputDocument, TraceWriter log)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myIoTHubMessage))
        {
            // Parse the incoming IoT Hub message
            dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myIoTHubMessage);
    
            // Replace with your actual Cosmos DB endpoint and key
            string cosmosDbEndpoint = "";
            string cosmosDbKey = "";
    
            using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosDbEndpoint), cosmosDbKey))
            {
                // Replace with your actual database and container name
                string databaseId = "";
                string containerId = "";
    
                // Create a new document for Azure Cosmos DB
                var document = new
                {
                    id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    partitionKey = "",
                    temperature = message.temperature // Assuming your IoT Hub message has a "temperature" field
                };
    
                Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, containerId);
    
                // Insert the document into Cosmos DB
                await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, document);
    
                // Return the document to be stored in Azure Cosmos DB
                outputDocument = document;
            }introducir el código aquí
        }
        else
        {
            outputDocument = null;
        }
    }

    pero cuando hago un test me sale 
    HTTP response code
    202 Accepted
    y me sale un error de falta de dependencias
```

[Error]   Function compilation error
[Error]   run.csx(1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client' could not be found
[Error]   run.csx(3,23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Documents' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
[Error]   run.csx(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[Error]   run.csx(8,65): error CS1988: Async methods cannot have ref, in or out parameters
[Warning]   run.csx(8,81): warning CS0618: 'TraceWriter' is obsolete: 'Will be removed in an upcoming version. Use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger instead.'
[Error]   run.csx(13,27): error CS0103: The name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context
[Error]   run.csx(19,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DocumentClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[Error]   run.csx(33,33): error CS0103: The name 'UriFactory' does not exist in the current context
[Error]   Executed 'Functions.PFF' (Failed, Id=634d8fb3-a847-4eb4-934a-bfd2440e735b, Duration=489ms)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.